# Same function but in different variables

Tags: functions

I am trying to define free fall velocity as a function of time and a function of distance i.e.

$$v(t) = v_0-gt$$

and
$$v(y) = \sqrt {v_0^2-2g(y-y_0)}$$

These are essentially the same function considering $y(t) = y_0+v_0 t- \frac 1 2g t^2$. In Mathematica I would like to find if there is a way to define these two functions without having to give them differenty names as this would be cumbersome. They are really the same function but in different variables.

It seems the "function" object in mathematica has a hard time doing this. I have also looked into creating two seperate `Context` objects, namely a `yFunction` and `tFunction` context class aside from the `Global` context and defining each set of functions there. This seems way too complicated especially since the variables in question, $y$ and $t$ are really global variables and the constants I would like to use would be common to both functions. Is there a quick and dirty way to do this without the ugliness of renaming each function seperately?

Comment: So how do you expect `v[0]` to be calculated?

Comment: How about `v[t_,"t"]:= v0 - g t` and `v[y_,"y"]:= Sqrt[v0^2-2g(y-y0)]` or `v[t_]:= v0 - g t` and `v[{y_}]:= Sqrt[v0^2-2g(y-y0)]`

Comment: what does the ,"t"] after the v[t_ do? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation....

Comment: If you want to evaluate the function at `t = 2` you would write `v[2, "t"]` its just an arbitrary pattern. You could use any string you like

Comment: While these two functions express the same physical reality, they are not the "same function" because they operate on different variables and hence different mathematical spaces.  You must express them separately because (as pointed out), you must be able to distinguish $v(t=0)$ from $v(y=0)$, and the variables are expressed in different units.

Comment: I voted to close this question because I believe it is unclear/too broad unless you answer the first comment.

Comment: How about v[0, "t"] and v[0,"y"].

Comment: In this case Mathematica will give you either `v0` or `Sqrt[v0^2+2g y0]`. Just test it!

Comment: Yes. It works. Therefore the first comment has been answered and addressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica can not distinguish the pattern in the argument of `v[t_]:= v0 - g t` from the pattern in the argument of `v[y_]:= Sqrt[v0^2-2g(y-y0)]`.

Funtion overloading (as this is called) in simple in Mathematica if an additional pattern is included in the definition:

```
v[t_,"t"]:= v0 - g t
v[y_,"y"]:= Sqrt[v0^2-2g(y-y0)]
```